# Redraw cells after UICollectionViewFlowLayout invalidates its layout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

When you invalidate layout on a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` it creates a bunch of new layout attributes for each of your cells; it doesn't tell your cells to redraw however, which causes distortions in any Layer drawings.

I don't want to tell my collection to reload its data because this removes any nice transitions you have between flow attributes : I have a grid layout transitioning into a coverflow for example.

I need a way for the `UICollectionViewController` class to tell the cells to call their `[setNeedsDisplay]` method after being given the layout attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your cells change size, it's up to them how to handle that (stretching vs redrawing). This is controlled by the UIView `contentMode` property; try setting it to `UIViewContentModeRedraw` to cause resizing to invalidate your views contents like `setNeedsDisplay:` would.

If you're using CALayers directly as sub-layers of your cell, you can set their `needsDisplayOnBoundsChange` to `YES` in order to get the same effect.

Comment: needsDisplayOnBoundsChange is OSX only I believe. UIViewContentModeRedraw works but slows it down a tad during the layout transitions. You're right though, the views need to handle their own state. I'll use the contentMode property. Thanks.

Comment: @LeeProbert You're welcome. The docs seem to say that needsDisplayOnBoundsChange is on CALayer from iOS 2 and up.

Comment: yea, you're correct. I can't seem to get it to recognise the property.

Comment: weird : https://www.evernote.com/shard/s4/sh/9bd7c9c0-3a80-46b2-bd31-b68426db4202/1a7a58be89f77e9abec62618b65cacb9

Comment: The key in that error message is "on *forward* class CALayer"; this means it can't find a definition for CALayer and so none of its methods will be available. Try `#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in this file (and add to your project if needed).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'd thought it was included in my prefix file. Thanks for your help. This works a treat.