# Recreating the whole UICollectionView vs invalidating the UICollectionView layout on an orientation change

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a horrible problem that is worthy of a separate stackoverflow question. Perhaps I can save time by asking a different question:

What are the downsides to recreating the whole `UICollectionView` layout on every device rotation rather than invalidating the `UICollectionView` layout with invalidateLayout?

Bare in mind that its a small view with a maximum of 6 text based cells - not a lot of data.

This question is a follow on from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956914/uibutton-contraints-in-two-layouts). I implemented the UICollection view and everything is working except the first two buttons inside the cells aren’t changing width on a orientation change, its a mess. Its almost like the method to update the cells is definitely being called but with the data from the last orientation view. Even after lots of debugging I'm still unsure exactly what the problem is.

**Update**

I managed to solve my nightmare with the information from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364913/redraw-cells-after-uicollectionviewflowlayout-invalidates-its-layout) and the actual code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134035/how-to-manage-uiimageview-content-mode). But if someone can still answer this question it would be helpful and interesting, I still want to know the answer!